# scss error on rbga 256 color

Tags: css, sass

My designer gave me this css:

```
.wrapper {
   margin:10px auto 0;
   border:5px solid #3c3c3c;
   background:rgba(256,256,256,0.80);
}
```

It works fine in a css file, and he says it is valid (I guess that is how he does transparency)

When I put it in a scss file it gives this error:

$red: Color value 256 must be between 0 and 255 for `rgba'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS is parsing and evaluating this expression, including values for the rgba function. Value for each color component can be between 0 and FF (or 255). 256 is an invalid value.

Having said that, browsers are quite flexible with CSS interpretation (apparently more flexible than SASS) and they treat 256 as 255 (at least Chrome does).

I guess, to fix this issue - try replace 256 with 255.

Answer (score 1):

While your CSS technically validates, it does raise warnings.  From the validator:

> 256 is out of range

Browsers are expected to gracefully clamp the values like so (also from the validator):

```
.wrapper  { 
    margin : 10px auto 0; 
    border : #3c3c3c solid 5px; 
    background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); 
}
```

Sass is a little more strict about this since you're invoking the `rgba()` function which explicitly requires the arguments to fall within a specific range: 0-255.

Comment: By the way, your border is backwards.

Comment: @Anonymous "My" border is not backwards, it was copied it from the validator.  Any complaint should be raised with the maintainers.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using a different validator as a reference (unless that is some new syntax for the border property that I didn't know about). :)